# Cancel order and restore products stock qty

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, stock, quantity

I'm using the following code to cancel programmatically some orders in my magento website:

```
foreach($orderCollection as $order):
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($order->getId());

    $order->setData('state', "canceled");
    $order->setStatus("canceled");       
    $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order was automatically canceled');
    $order->save();

    Mage::getModel('jewelsales/order_synch')->cancelOrder($order->getId());
endforeach;
```

The problem is that the order's product quantities, that were decreased when order was placed, are not increased back their previous state, after order is canceled.

Can you help me fix that?

***Note:** Product quantities are restored if I cancel order through magento administration. But it's not working when canceling orders programmatically.

Comment: please try my solution as below

Answer (score 1):

Why you use external cancel functionality to load model each time, Magento Provide **cancle()** function.

Try This code to cancel order:

```
if(!$order->canCancel()) {
    throw new Exception('Order cannot be canceled anymore.');
}
$order->cancel();
$order->save();
```

I give you such idea to use `cancel()`  like:-

```
$orderModel = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
$orderModel->load($orderId);
if(!$orderModel->canCancel()) {
$orderModel->cancel();
$orderModel->setState(Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED, true);
$orderModel->save();
}
```

**System->Configuration-> Catalog ->inventory->stock options->Set Items' Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled change this value to "No".**

**You can also stop to decrease the stock quantity on order placed: System->Configuration-> catalog  -> inventory->stock options->Decrease Stock When Order is Placed**

Comment: I tried using your code but still the product qty is not restored.

Comment: hey have you check configuration,  i just edit my answer  @zekia

Comment: I need to keep increasing/decreasing stock quantities. This is not a solution for my ehop.  As I mentioned in my question, product quantities are restored if I cancel order through magento administration. But it's not working when canceling orders programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try below code for cancel order and manage inventory of Products ordered. Its working fine for me :

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);  
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementID('100000015'); // Your order increment id
$order->cancel()->save();
```

Comment: I tested the code and it's not canceling the order. Any ideas?

Comment: @zekia , code updated.

Comment: I'm running this through an .sh file, in case that matters at all

Comment: Can you try this script for manually in browser?

Comment: I'll try this, but my initial script loads and cancels order normally. I think that the `$order->cancel()->save();` is not working in your code. I'll let you know in a while

Comment: @zekia ,  For make "$order->cancel()->save();" working you need to add "Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID); "

Comment: yea I did add `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);` but still not working

Comment: I also tried setting the store hardcoded, like `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(0);` but still not working

Comment: Please try custom code then "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330140/magento-increase-qty-upon-cancel-a-shipped-order"

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked in  **`Magento 2`**

Automatically cancel pending payment orders older than 1 day using **cron**

Create a custom module with required files

**`Custom/Module/etc/crontab.xml`**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="order_cancel_orders" instance="Custom\Module\Cron\OrderCancelOrders" method="execute">
            <schedule>*/5 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

**`Custom/Module/Cron/OrderCancelOrders.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Cron;

use Exception;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class OrderCancelOrders
{

    protected $productRepository;
    protected $dateTime;
    protected $logger;
    protected $date;
    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    protected $orderManagement;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        DateTime $dateTime,
        TimezoneInterface $date,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        OrderManagementInterface $orderManagement
    )
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->dateTime = $dateTime;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->date = $date;
        $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->orderManagement = $orderManagement;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->logger->info('Orders Cancel cron job running');
        $date = (new \DateTime())->modify('-1 day');
        $this->logger->info('Date'.$date);
        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter(
                'status',
                'pending_payment',
                'eq'
            )->addFilter(
                'created_at',
                $date->format('Y-m-d'),
                'gt'
            )->setPageSize(
                10
            )->create();
        try {
            $ordersData = $this->orderRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
            foreach ($ordersData->getItems() as $orders) {
                if ($orders->getId()) {
                    $this->orderManagement->cancel($orders->getId());
                    $this->logger->info("OrderID# {$orders->getId()} OrderIncrementID# {$orders->getIncrementId()} successfully order canceled and reverted stock.");
                }
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```