# Magento 1.9: Revert the inventory if cancel the order from back-end by admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, backend, cancel-orders

How to do inventory back if order cancel from backend by admin?

Comment: check here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/226523/cancel-order-and-restore-products-stock-qty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

login to admin panel

go to `system->configuration->catalog->inventory` and set **Set Items Status** to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled to yes

https://drops.meetanshi.com/NaNoyG

Answer (score 1):

You can configure it from the Magento configuration by following below steps:

> Go to Magento Admin > System > Configuration > Catalog > Inventory

Below is the screenshot for more information

[image].

**Hope it helps!!!**